# Validation for html5 input type number

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to show 2 different validation messages for the following input type

```
<input type="number" step="1" formControlName="Ordinal" />
```

I'm using reactive forms with a formGroup that is similar to this

```
formBuilder.group({
  ..
  Ordinal: [0, [Validators.required, CustomValidators.integer]],
  ..
});
```

One Validator `Validators.required` should show a required message if there is no input at all. The other Validator `Validator.integer` should show a message if an invalid number is entered.

The current implementation of Validation.integer looks like this

```
export function integer(control: FormControl) {
  const value = control.value;
  if ((parseFloat(value) === parseInt(value, 10)) && !isNaN(value) || value === '' || value === null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return {
      notNumeric: true
    };
  }
}
```

My problem is that with `type="number"` the browser returns `null` in both cases (when input is empty / when number is invalid).
How can i distinguish these two states?

Comment: why do you this conditon for?
(parseFloat(value) === parseInt(value, 10)

Comment: Just checking if it's an integer or not. But good question why i didn't just use Number.isInteger(). To be honest i don't remember, it's quite a while ago when i first wrote this

Answer (score 0):

```
    to check numeric value I thinks `isNaN and  Number.isInteger()` would be enough 

    Please check the following updated conditions :-


    export function integer(control: FormControl) {
      const value = control.value;
      if(value === 'null' || value === undefined || value === '' ){
       return isRequired: true
      }
     else if ((!Number.isInteger(value) || !isNaN(value))) {
        return null;
      } else {`enter code here`
        return {
          notNumeric: true
        };
      }
    }


    hope this helps
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that. But this does not solve my main problem, that i cannot distinguish between the two cases (no input -> required validation & wrong input -> integer validation). I need two different validation messages and for that i need two different validators (or at least two different return values). Since both states return null, i cannot check them seperately.

Comment: I've updated my answer please check. Now you can also check for required condition

Comment: That will not work since the value is `null` if it's an invalid input. So i'll get `isRequired` instead of `notNumeric`